# Is it possible to use a Bluetooth dongle on a Windows 10 laptop that already has Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I'm using a sensor that talks to my PC via serial over Bluetooth.  I've had trouble getting it to run on all but one type of Bluetooth dongle.  Now, I need to buy another laptop.  I would like to play it safe and get a laptop without Bluetooth and just use the same dongle as before.  But, I can't find any laptops that don't already have Bluetooth installed.  Is it possible to still use my old Bluetooth dongle on those?

Comment: I have done that with Windows 8.1, I don't know why it wouldn't work with Win 10.

Comment: Sure, why not? At the very least, if needed, you can disable the built in Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I use a bluetooth mouse dongle on my Windows 10 tablet which also has built-in bluetooth (which I use for the keyboard), so I'll say yes.  The best approach would probably be to borrow a similar model and try it yourself, though.